# Authentic resources to learn about Buddha's Dharma

Tags: buddha

I was on a project to read bhagvat geeta and understand it's true meaning by myself (since I was baffled by plenty of commentaries done by others). It's 4th *adhyaya* and I am convinced that this text is written with intention to cover failures of orthodox religion under god's name. The indirect attack on teachings of Buddha(little of which I know) is also evident in some verses. Nonetheless, I want to look for pure knowledge about myself and troubles I am going through and this time it's through Buddha. I am not new to Buddhism but I want to start from scratch,From where should I start? Which is the best book/resource to get authentic information about core of Buddha's teachings?

Comment: Try searching this site for "[books](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/search?q=books)".

Comment: See also [English (or other European) translations of Pali Canon](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/4109/254) -- that's about the "Pali Canon" which though it's important isn't the only school of Buddhism or only "Buddha Dharma" -- but it's maybe a good start!

Comment: In addition to those duplicates, also: [Starting Buddhism](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/20182/471), [Recommendation - Book for beginner](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/12794/471)

Comment: My personal favorite to recommend a complete newcomer to read is "[Without and Within](https://www.withoutandwithin.net/wp-content/uploads/2020/12/WithoutAndWithinEnglish.pdf)" by Ven. Ajahn Jayasaro.

Answer (score 0):

You can start with summaries of Pali scriptures, such as:

1. [Constitution for Living: Buddhist Principles for a Fruitful and Harmonious Life – P.A. Payutto](https://www.mahidol.ac.th/budsir/Contents.html)
2. [In the Buddha's Words - Bhikkhu Bodhi](https://www.dhammawheel.com/viewtopic.php?t=14640)